# Does reloading a page makes the whole angular app re-running?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two pages in my app. When I refresh or reload it by pressing the url in urlbar, I found out my inserted data in both pages are gone. Does this conclude to the app gets re-instantiated or re run thus the dynamically inserted changes are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the app doesn't re-run.
Reloading the page means the page itself gets re-rendered. So, if you make some local changes on the web-page which isn't persistent - means which isn't stored in some Database those changes will not persist and will not be reflected after you reload your page.

Comment: Can you please tell me where re-rendered differ from re-run?

Comment: And why reloading a different page makes another page to be re-rendered.

Comment: Running an angular app (with "ng serve") creates a server instance is created on port 4200, all typescript code gets converted to Javascript (since Typescript isn't understood by browser) and all HTML and CSS files are bundled along with that and stored in dist folder in your project directory. Then all those files will be deployed to server running on port 4200 and hence when you type localhost:4200 in URL bar, you can see web page. Re-running angular app typically means this process of conversion, bundling and deploying happening again.

Comment: When you refresh the web page, the content of that web page simply is fetched again from server which is already running on port 4200. However, the app itself isn't re-running.
For example, when you refresh google home page your web browser simply fetches the content of that page from a google server (that's re-rendering or refreshing the page). But, the google server itself isn't re-running. The server is already running with the content of home page already in it and you're simply asking for that content again by refreshing the page.

Comment: thanks bro. Your ideas makes those concepts more clear to me.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer accepted if it had cleared your doubt, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "*re-instantiated or re run*" as these terms are not well defined.

First, you need to realize that Angular runs in a browser window, which I think you do. The browser is your platform on which the Angular app is built, just as the OS is the platform on which the browser is built.

When you load a web page, the browser clears out any existing page. When you refresh a page, you are starting all over again with a new version of the same page.

The closest analogy is an OS reboot. If an application is running and hasn't saved its state to disk or cloud storage then, when the application is restarted after the system has rebooted, your application will not remember the previous state and your data will be lost.

Similarly, if your browser "reboots" the web page and your web application hasn't saved its state to disk (via Local Storage or IndexedDB) or cloud storage (a server or database) then, when your web app reloads after the page has finished refreshing, your web app will not remember the previous state and your data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

On reload, your angularJS app will rerun it's initializations, but the code itself may be cached to your browser. Any cached `$http` responses you've made before reload will not be cached in angular (though your browser might have cached them). `$scope` variables that you changed will not be remembered after reload.

To remember `$scope` variables you can use a package like [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), or use the built-in `localStorage` object via `$window` (which you'll need to inject).

```
$window.localStorage.setItem(key,value)
$window.localStorage.getItem(key)
```